# Converting a C implementation of OpenSSL to Ruby code

Tags: c, ruby, openssl

In C I can do the following:

```
bignum = BN_new();
BN_bin2bn(my_message, 32, bignum);
group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
ecp = EC_POINT_new(group);
check = EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp(group, ecp, bignum, 0, NULL);
key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
check = EC_KEY_set_public_key(key, ecp);
check = EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(public_key, key);
```

In Ruby, I thought this would do the same thing, but I get an error*

```
bignum = OpenSSL::BN.new(my_message, 2)
group = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Group.new('prime256v1')
group.point_conversion_form = :compressed
public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point.new(group, bignum)
```

In both instances I can log bignum and see that it is the same, and I'm pretty positive `prime256v1` is the correct group.

In both cases C and Ruby are using the same version of OpenSSL (OpenSSL 1.0.2p 14 Aug 2018)

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here would be massively appreciated.

*The error message I get is `invalid encoding (OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point::Error)`

Comment: Hi, do you have the statement require 'openssl'?

Comment: Sorry I should have included in the snippet, but yes, all required libraries are included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp` function in C expects you to pass in the x-coordinate of the point and separately a value to specify which of the two possible points it could be (you are passing in a literal `0`, in reality you should determine the actual value).

In Ruby, the `Point` initializer is expecting the point encoded as a string that includes information about both coordinates (I don’t know if this format has a name, but it’s pretty common and is documented by the [SECG](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf)). In the case of compressed coordinates this string is basically the same 32 bytes as in the C code, but with an extra byte at the start, either `0x02` or `0x03`, which correspond to passing `0` or `1` as the y-bit to `EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp`.

If the string doesn’t start with `0x02` or `0x03` (or `0x04` for uncompressed points) or is the wrong length, then you will get the `invalid encoding` error.

It doesn’t look like the Ruby OpenSSL bindings provide a way to specify a point using separate x and y coordinates. The simplest way would be to add the `0x02` or `0x03` prefix to the string before passing it to `Point.new`.

If you already have this string you can use it in C to create a point using [`EC_POINT_oct2point`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EC_POINT_new.html). Ruby itself [calls `EC_POINT_oct2point`](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/v2.1.2/ext/openssl/ossl_pkey_ec.c#L1369) if you pass a string to `Point.new`.